# Get Data from Table and put inside MySQL using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

What I am trying to do is to insert data from input fields then get this data into array and put this data inside MySQL database.

I got the value from the input then it added to the table using a button how can I get this data rows and put it inside MYSQL Database using PHP.

HTML

```
<table id="expTable">
            <thead>
             <tr>
                <th class="tdn">Name</th>
                <th class="tdn">From</th>
                <th class="tdn">To</th>
                <th class="tdn">Desc</th>

             </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
           
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

JavaScript

```
function insertData(){

    var compName = $('input[name="name"]').val();
    var workFrom = $('input[name="from"]').val();
    var workTo = $('input[name="to"]').val();
    var desc = $('textarea[name="desc"]').val();
    
    var addTr = '<tr><td class="tdn">' + compName + '</td>  <td class="tdn">' +workFrom+ 
    '</td>  <td class="tdn">' + workTo + '</td>  <td class="tdn">' + desc + '</td></tr>';

    $('tbody').append(addTr);
}
```

Comment: submit that data using `<form>`  or use `ajax`

Comment: Where is your database? Remote or local?

Comment: local database with wampserver

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i am stuck at getting these rows from table to put it inside a variable array inside PHP .

Answer (score 0):

Usually you send the gathered data `JSON`-formatted as asynchronous request (AJAX) to a backend (in 2020 it is a rest-api) .

The called endpoint checks the input validity and stores the data in the database and returns a http 200 ok. Or if not ok a corresponding error message and status code.

If you will do so, you need a second programm (the rest-api) which stores the data for you. If you like to stay on php https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/08/simple-rest-api-php might help.

Comment: sorry i am new into that where can i learn this kind of things ?

Comment: Have as look at http request and response, http status code, rest api: https://www.restapitutorial.com/ , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes , https://www.oreilly.com/content/http-with-php/

Comment: If you want only connect your database have look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

Comment: Thank you for this information nologin ,i will sure look forward for this things :)